# Reorder the auto increment value while working in java

Tags: java

I have ID as primary key and enabled the auto increment in ID. Now suppose if ID are

```
1 ram
2 shyam
3 hari
4 sita
```

If I delete id and tries to add new value database will have

```
1 ram
2 shyam
4 sita
5 themos
```

But I want it to be

```
1 ram
2 shyam
3 sita
4 themos
```

I want to implement this through java code.

Answer (score 2):

You have selected an auto incrementing db key and it is doing what it is supposed to do.

Any gaps in the sequence due to deletions should not be of concern to you. If they are then you have a broken db design.

Otherwise if you really must then use temp tables to move the data out and back in to do this or do some really silly complicated locking to handle delete marks to overwrite for later inserts which like I said would be silly. Oh and then deal with the consequences of cooking live data.

Much simpler to fix your broken db design.